# Entity Framework with Oracle

Tags: entity-framework, odac

I have installed the ODAC 11 and I would like to use it with EF Database First but it doesn't appear in the "Choose Data Source" dialog just the SQL Server providers.
I don't know how to go further.
I need a little help, please.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you installed, but [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html) has support for Entity Framework.  I've used it before with no issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've used this: ODAC112030_x64. I've added the Oracle.DataAccess to the References. But when I've created a new database connection the data Source is 'Oracle Database (OracleClient)' and not 'Oracle Database (Oracle ODP.NET). I do not understand.